# How does the kernel know if the CPU is in user mode or kenel mode?

Tags: linux-kernel

Since the CPU runs in user/kernel mode, I want to know how this is determined by kernel. I mean, if a sys call is invoked, the kernel executes it on behalf of the process, but how does the kernel know that it is executing in kernel mode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CPU Switches from User mode to Kernel Mode : What exactly does it do? How does it makes this transition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479118/cpu-switches-from-user-mode-to-kernel-mode-what-exactly-does-it-do-how-does-it)

Comment: maybe you mean user-context/process-context vs kernel-context/interrupt-context?

Answer (score 42):

You can tell if you're in user-mode or kernel-mode from the privilege level set in the code-segment register (CS).  Every instruction loaded into the CPU from the memory pointed to by the RIP or EIP register (the instruction pointer register depending on if you are x86_64 or x86 respectively) will read from the segment described in the global descriptor table (GDT) by the current code-segment descriptor.  The lower two-bits of the code segment descriptor will determine the current privilege level that the code is executing at.  When a syscall is made, which is typically done through a software interrupt, the CPU will check the current privilege-level, and if it's in user-mode, will exchange the current code-segment descriptor for a kernel-level one as determined by the syscall's software interrupt gate descriptor, as well as make a stack-switch and save the current flags, the user-level CS value and RIP value on this new kernel-level stack.  When the syscall is complete, the user-mode CS value, flags, and instruction pointer (EIP or RIP) value are restored from the kernel-stack, and a stack-switch is made back to the current executing processes' stack.

Comment: This is a very enriching comment, thank you. +1. If you happened to have some documentation to read further on this, I’d love to know more about it.

Comment: Protection levels, and how to detect them, are documented in the [Intel Developer's Guide](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), Volume 3A, chapter 5.

Comment: @Jason, isn't actually the code segment selector you're referring to when you say `The lower two-bits of the code segment descriptor ` ?

Comment: @ngwdaniel Hey Daniel, can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 7):

Broadly if it's running kernel code it's in kernel mode. The transition from user-space to kernel mode (say for a system call) causes a context switch to occur. As part of this context switch the CPU mode is changed.

Answer (score 3):

Kernel code only executes in kernel mode. There is no way, kernel code can execute in user mode. When application calls system call, it will generate a trap (software interrupt) and the mode will be switch to kernel mode and kernel implementation of system call will executed. Once it is done, kernel will switch back to user mode and user application will continue processing in user mode.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 2):

The term is called "Superviser Mode", which applies to x86/ARM and many other processor as well.

Read this (which applies only to x86 CPU):

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(computer_security)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28computer_security%29)

Ring 0 to 3 are the different privileges level of x86 CPU.   Normally only Ring0 and 3 are used (kernel and user), but nowadays Ring 1 find usages (eg, VMWare used it to emulate guest's execution of ring 0).   Only Ring 0 has the full privilege to run some privileged instructions (like lgdt, or lidt), and so a good test at the assembly level is of course to execute these instruction, and see if your program encounters any exception or not.

Read this to really identify your current privilege level (look for CPL, which is a pictorialization of Jason's answer):

http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/cpu-rings-privilege-and-protection

Comment: first link is not a proper link.

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple question and does not need any expert comment as provided above..

The question is how does a cpu come to know whether it is kernel mode or its a user mode.
The answer is "mode bit"....

It is a bit in Status register of cpu's registers set. 
When "mode bit=0",,,it is considered as kernel mode(also called,monitor mode,privileged mode,protected mode...and many other...)
When "mode bit=1",,it is considered as User mode...and user can now perform its personal applications without any special kernel interruption.

so simple...isn't it??

Comment: less details are provided. as this question expect elaboration but not a well elaborated answered.